# Cannot deserialize instance of date JSON_PARSER_ERROR when no date present while patching

Tags: json, error-messages, httprequest, google-apps, patch

I am working with a Google Apps Script to upload data into Salesforce.  Everything works except I am running into this error when a date is not present in a date field, which happens only occasionally throughout my sheet.  I am wondering what my options are to prevent this from happening?

My payload looks like this, where the xxx is censored information:

```
{"Name":"xxx","BillingStreet":"xxx","BillingCity":"xxx","BillingState":"xxx","BillingPostalCode":"xxx","Billing_Contact__c":"","Phone":"xxx","Billing_Email__c":"","Active_customer__c":"Y","Last_Invoice_Date__c":"","Account_Creation_Date__c":"xxx"}
```

The full error I am receiving is this:

```
[{"message":"Cannot deserialize instance of date from VALUE_STRING value  or request may be missing a required field at [line:1, column:268]","errorCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR"}]
```

Last_Invoice_Date__c is the only field that may or may not have a date, and the error seems to only happen when the date is not present.  How can I patch this with an empty field?

To add to this, it only happens on the date fields.

Answer (score 2):

Found my answer.  I passed the field as a null instead of a 0 length string and that corrected it.